# streaming log files using apache storm

Tags: apache-storm

I am new to storm i would like to know is there any possibilities to read server log files using storm, if it is possible how to read the file and how to to get the error messages which was written in the log files.

Comment: Where do you store your log files? `S3` , `HDFS`, local file system, `DB` ??? Are you familiar with any messaging systems?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use something like Apache Flume instead of Storm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure your `spout` to read from the log file and emit per line as it reads the log. The output then can be given to a bolt for analyzing if it is an error or whatever your requirement is.